# Ignoring all line feeds in a FreeMarker template

Tags: java, freemarker

I'm trying out FreeMarker, not for a web application but to generate text within a desktop application.  I'd like to get the text without any linefeeds, however it always appends a linefeed. For example, this would produce "blah blah\n"

```
<#if docType=1>
blah blah
<#if docType=2>
more blah
<#/if>
```

Any ideas? Bunching it all into one line works, but is horrible. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See perhaps [White-space handling](http://freemarker.org/docs/dgui_misc_whitespace.html#dgui_misc_whitespace_stripping), **ftl** and **compress** directives. But you can't suppress all linefeeds.

Another solution : filter the output, and replace \n by " ".

Comment: Thanks - actually I've found you can compress all line feeds. 
    <@compress single_line=true>
    </@compress>

Answer (score 2):

I would also take a look at [t,lt, and rt directives](http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/docs/ref_directive_t.html).

Using your example,

```
<#if docType=1>
blah blah <#t>
<#if docType=2>
more blah<#t> 
<#/if>
```

Should produce `blah blah more blah` on a single line

Answer (score 1):

```
<@compress single_line=true>...</@compress>
```

...this will output everything in between the compress tag as one line.